# show my public ssh keys, a good idea?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

If I have many public ssh keys.

Is a good idea show all of my public keys in web page?
maybe a [gist](http://gist.github.com) or similar .

### EDIT

my problem is : when I create a new server, I have to manually copy the keys.

Comment: good idea ? That entirely depends on why you want people to have your public ssh keys.

Comment: Join the crowd: https://gist.github.com/gists/search?q=ssh+public+key&page=1

Comment: @cjc , this guys share one key, I talk of the all of my keys

Comment: Make sure you don't ignore any "HOST KEY IS DIFFERENT!1!" messages you get from your SSH client though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, share away. There's a reason they are called **public** keys.

Comment: Unless there's some specific reason you don't want anyone to know that a particular public key is yours, there's no reason to keep them secret. (For example, one reason might be if you have access to a very critical machine and fear a [$5 wrench attack](http://xkcd.com/538/).)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good point.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can share your public key, it only can be used by you and nobody else as you the only one who has private key and without that key public key is useless, so you can share with everyone it makes no difference to you if someone else got it unless you have private key.